# Why UI in Winforms can be updated inside while loop with async operation?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I am new in Async/Await operation. So after i read docs and research about it with practise. I got this which i do not know how it work behind the scene.

This code free UI obviously:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // ui thread - sync
        }
    }
```

But this is not free UI:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); // async 
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // ui thread - sync
        }
    }
```

In my mind after Task.Delay finished, remaining code will run on UI thread but while loop stop rendering UI. I am stuck at this point !

My question is why UI can be updated if i use async method inside?

Please ask me more if question not clearly. Thank you.

Comment: When you click your button, the thread is stuck on the infinite loop in either case. Could you clarify your question ?

Comment: thank for helping me, so in first case my app free all the time rather second case my app responsive and label was updated every each one second.

Comment: is there any luck for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often people think that when async-await is used the job is done by separate threads. In fact all work is done by one thread. This thread will do all normal work until it sees an await. Instead of really waiting for the function to complete it goes up its call stack to see it the caller has something to do ( = to see if the caller is not awaiting), it performs the statements until the caller has to await. The thread goes up in the call stack to see if it can do something else until an await, etc. Once the complete call stack is awaiting it checks if the original await is already finished. If so the thread continues with the statements after the await, if not the thread comes to a halt until the task is really finished.

So as long as somewhere in the thread there is no await, your thread can do other things instead of waiting.

```
private async Task A()
{
    Do1();
    var taskB = B(); // call B without await
    Do2();
    await taskB;     // wait for B to finish
    Do3();
}

private async Task B()
{
    Do4();
    var taskC = C(); // call C without await
    Do5();
    await taskC;     // wait for C to finish
    Do6();
}

private async Task C()
{
    Do7();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
    Do8();
}
```

Once A() is called, you'll see that the following are called: Do1; B; Do4; C; Do7; Task.Delay, where the thread meets the first await.

Because of async-await the thread doesn't wait in C for Task.Delay.

Instead the thread goes up its call stack to see if it can do something in B. In the example, B is not awaiting yet, so Do5 is called. Now we meet the await in B. The thread still doesn't wait, but goes up in its call stack to procedure A to see if it can do something in A. And indeed, because A is not awaiting after calling B, Do2 can be called. Then A starts awaiting. The thread goes up in its call stack to see ..., etc.

Once everyone in the call stack is awaiting the thread goes back to Task.Delay and really starts waiting until the time elapses. After the await the thread knows that everyone in the call stack is awaiting.

The thread continues with Do8 and goes up its call stack to continue after the first await after the call to C. (after all it knows that everyone was awaiting). There Do6 is called, and the thread returns to the statement after the await in A: Do3.

So you see that async-await influences the order in which procedures are called. Therefore you need to await for any procedure where you need the results from.

So if in the example Do2 needs the result of anything happening in B() (and thus in Do4/Do5/Do6/C/Do7/Do8), we should await B() before calling Do2.

Note that it looks as if several things are performed simultaneously, but in fact they are all done separately by the same thread.

Eric Lippert compared this behaviour with a cook in a restaurant: [Eric Lippert about async-await](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). Search somewhere in the middle for async await: if the cook toasts bread he doesn't wait until the bread is toasted, but starts boiling water to cook the eggs. The cook will not put bread in the toaster and water in the sauce pan at the same time, but instead of waiting for one thing he'll start doing the other things where he doesn't need the toasted bread.

Another link for async-await that helped me a lot to understand it: [Stephen Cleary about async and await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Now back to your question.

In your first example you wrote: **This code free UI obviously:**
I assume you mean: This code freezes the UI obviously. And indeed it does.

In your 2nd example the thread doesn't start doing nothing when it awaits Task.Delay. Instead it goes up its call steck to see if it can do something else, like reacting on mouse clicks. That's how it keeps the UI alive.

Comment: thank you so much because took time to do a good explaination for me. I am very appreciated about that and will research more on the links that you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

When the code hits the `await`, the code will enqueue a *continuation* on the `Delay` task and then leave the UI thread. That means for the next second, the UI thread is free to do any rendering work it needs.

After the one second elapses, the `Task` completes, the continuation is executed on the UI thread (thanks to a `SynchronizationContext`) and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! i will research more and more.